# I am considering

Tags: gerunds

*I am considering to meet you next Friday.*

*I am considering meeting you next Friday.*

I would like to ask you:

1. Is the continuous form (consider) possible in my sentence?
2. Is it possible to use the gerund as well as the infinitive?

Comment: You should note that ***considering*** is very likely not a good choice here. In such contexts, ***to be considering** [something that involves another person]* usually carries very strong implications that ***the speaker / writer is in control*** (and ***may***, if so inclined, come to a decision that favours or disadvantages the other party). To avoid any such implications, you need to rephrase in a way that expresses your desire for the meeting date to be ***mutually agreeable***.

Comment: ***I was wondering whether it would suit you for us to meet next Friday***, perhaps. But more naturally, just ask ***Would it be convenient for us to meet next Friday?***

Comment: It's a very useful comment for me. I thought that when I use the verb "consider" I just express that I seriously think about to do something without the implication of personal superiority.

Comment: I guessed you wouldn't be aware of that "implicit sub-text". In fact, ***I am considering [doing X]*** is very often used in contexts where if you do *in fact* decide to do X, this will be to the detriment of the addressee. For example, a disgruntled customer saying ***I am considering taking my business elsewhere*** (= *I will buy from a different supplier, **if** you don't improve the way you serve me*) - where it's effectively a "threat". You obviously don't want any implications of that in your context. (I hope! :)

Comment: So when I use "I am considering meeting you", it, in fact, means that the free will of the addressee is limited. I have decided and you must respect it.

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better do not use *considering*, as an alternative you can say/write:

> I plan to meet you next Friday.

Comment: Yes, ***plan*** seems a good verb choice here. If OP wishes to be "polite / deferential", this could easily be covering by appending ***...if that's convenient for you***.